Genesis 4:1 (was Eve speaking about Adam or Cain, or both?)
Genesis 4:1 KJV
And Adam knew Eve his wife; and she conceived, and bare Cain, and said, I have gotten a man from the LORD.
From the Greek and Hebrew translations the root word for “a man” in this verse implies a husband. (Similar to Hosea 2:16 Ishi)
Eve is talking about Adam, not Cain.
Genesis 3:16 uses this word for children
https://biblehub.com/text/genesis/3-16.htm
Sounds illogical to refer to a newborn infant as being a man. I have not found one instance where the word “ish” has been used as a child, baby, infant ect.
https://biblehub.com/hebrew/ish_376.htm
God created Adam. Eve was created but not fully created by God from Adam. Adam was fully made in the image of God. Eve was not. Eve had gotten Adam from the LORD because God had created Adam. Eve had gotten Cain from Adam, not the LORD. A man translates to and fro to Adam in English, Eve had gotten Adam from the LORD

It is true that the Hebrew word אּישׁ (ish) can mean either "man" or "husband" depending on the context; for example:

"man" Gen 2:23, 24, 6:4, 7:2, 9:5, 10:5, 12:20, 13:13, 14:24, 17:23, etc.
"husband" Gen 3:6, 16, 29:32, 34, 30:18, 20, Lev 21:23, 7, etc.

In the case of Gen 4:1, the meaning cannot be "husband" as this would imply that Eve only obtained a husband at the birth of her child, Cain, an impossible interpretation as this would make Cain conception (without a valid husband) immoral.
Further, as the list above shows, Adam was already Eve's husband in Gen 3:6, 16.
Therefore, the only available translation of אּישׁ (ish) in Gen 4:1 is "man" or perhaps, "manchild" as per some versions.
The situation in the Greek LXX is even clearer - the word used in Gen 4:1 is ἄνθρωπος = "man" or "person".  Such almost never means "husband" as the word normally used for "husband" is ἀνήρ, ἀνδρός.

Adam was already called Eve's husband in chapter 3, and it's quite clear that the "man" she refers to is Cain (in his infant state), because the narrative immediately continues to describe the birth of Abel etc.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
